# If $\{ (λ-1)R(λ;T) \colon |λ|>1\}$ is bounded then so is $\{ (λ-1)R(λ;T) \colon |λ|=1, \ λ \neq 1\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

In [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123601937401) Proposition 2.2 states that the following are equivalent:

1. $T$ is power bounded and analytic.
2. $e^{t(T-I)}$ is a bounded analytic semigroup and $\sigma(T) \subset \mathbb D \cup \{1\}$.
3. $ \{ (λ-1)R(λ,T) \colon λ \in \overline{\mathbb D}{}^c \cup 1+Σ_δ \}$  is bounded for some  $δ>π/2$.
4. $ \{ (λ-1)R(λ,T) \colon λ \in  \overline{\mathbb D}{}^c\}$  is bounded.
5. $T$ is power bounded and  $ \{ (λ-1)R(λ,T) \colon |λ|=1, \ λ \neq 1 \}$  is bounded.

Power bounded means that $\sup_n \|T^n\|<\infty$ and analytic means that  $\sup_n \|n (T-I)T^n\|<\infty$. As always,  $R(λ;T) = (λ-T)^{-1}$ is the resolvent, $\mathbb D$ is the unit open disk and $Σ_θ =\{z \neq 0 \colon |\arg z| < θ\}$  is an open sector.

The author claims that $(4) \implies (5)$ is trivial. I do not actually see how this is trivial.

If we could show that $T$ is power bounded then it is fairly easy to show that $σ(T) \subset \mathbb D \cup \{1\}$ as
$\|(T-I)T^n\| \ge r\big( (T-I)T^n \big )$ and thus by the Spectral Mapping Theorem,
$$ |z-1| |z^n| \le \|(T-I)T^n\| \le \frac{M}{n+1} , \quad \forall z \in \sigma(T) .$$
Perhaps this can help showing that $ \{ (λ-1)R(λ,T) \colon |λ|=1, \ λ \neq 1 \}$  is bounded.

Here is an image that could be helpful:

[image]

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the first resolvent formula and $(4)$, you can show that the resolvent continuously extends to $\{|\lambda| = 1, \lambda \neq 1\}$. Indeed, consider such a $\lambda$ and take any sequence $(\lambda_n)_n \subset \overline{\mathbb D}{}^c$ converging to $\lambda$.
By assumption, there exists $M$ a positive constant such that:
$$\forall |\lambda'| > 1,\quad |\lambda' - 1| \|R(\lambda', T)\| \leq M < +\infty$$
Thus, we have:
$$\begin{split}\|R(\lambda_n, T) - R(\lambda_m, T)\| &= |\lambda_n - \lambda_m|\|R(\lambda_n, T)\|\|R(\lambda_m, T)\|\\
&\leq |\lambda_n - \lambda_m| \frac{M^2}{|\lambda_n - 1| |\lambda_m - 1|}\\
&\leq |\lambda_n - \lambda_m| \frac{M^2}{\inf_k |\lambda_k - 1|^2}\end{split}$$
The infimum involved is non-zero since $\lambda_n \to \lambda \neq 1$ and each $\lambda_n$ is different from $1$, hence $(R(\lambda_n, T))_n$ is Cauchy in the Banach space of bounded operators because $(\lambda_n)_n$ is Cauchy, which implies that it converges to some bounded operator $R_\lambda$.

Now, we need to justify that $R_\lambda$ does not depend on the choice of $(\lambda_n)_n$, but that's relatively straightforward: given two sequences $(\lambda_{1,n})_n$ and $(\lambda_{2,n})$, it suffices to look at the "alternating" sequence $(\lambda_n)_n$ defined by $\begin{cases}\lambda_{2n} := \lambda_{1,n}\\ \lambda_{2n+1} := \lambda_{2,n}\end{cases}$ and use the uniqueness of the limit to obtain that: $$R_{(\lambda, (\lambda_{1,n})_n)} = R_{(\lambda, (\lambda_n)_n)} = R_{(\lambda, (\lambda_{2,n})_n)}$$
where we temporarily introduced a notation for the $R_\lambda$ of each sequence.

Therefore, $\lambda' \mapsto R(\lambda', T)$ extends continuously to the boundary of the unit disk except for $1$. It's then quite simple to show that $R_\lambda$ satisfies $R(\lambda I - T) = (\lambda I - T)R_\lambda = I$ using this newfound continuity and the boundedness of $T$ thanks to the same equality applying for $R(\lambda', T)$ for $\lambda' \to \lambda$, which provides the existence of $R(\lambda, T)$ and the equality $R_\lambda = R(\lambda, T)$ for $|\lambda| = 1$, $\lambda \neq 1$.
It is then pretty clear that, by continuity, we also have $|\lambda - 1|\|R(\lambda, T)\| \leq M$ for the same $M$ as before, hence one half of the statement $(5)$.

---

EDIT 24/03/2024: It's been a few days, but I think I won't be able to come up with a direct proof for $(4) \Rightarrow (5)$, let alone a "trivial" one as per the author's words. However, the indirect way of proving it would be to assume that $(4) \Leftrightarrow (1)$ is known (it is shown in the paper by that point) for the powerbounded half and use what I said for the other half. Not that satisfying but
at least I hope that's what the author meant by trivial.

---

(I have my doubts on whether it is truly "trivial", though there could be a simpler argument, but there *is* a relative simplicity to the arguments I used. I also could have missed something or made some mistakes along the way, but hopefully not.)

Comment: @EvangelopoulosFoivos You are correct indeed, power series shenanigans do ensue here. I've edited my answer (I was overcomplicating that part).

Comment: How do you conclude that $\|T\| \le 1$? In [Theorem 4.5.4 of this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-8547-8) the author proves that the stronger condition (3) implies analycity and power boundedness of $T$. However, the proof is by no means elementary. Perhaps this seemingly innocent implication is not that innocent after all?

Comment: @EvangelopoulosFoivos I don't see a way to salvage what I've tried yet so I'll just leave it blank for now until/unless I find something.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosFoivos Edited my answer, I don't think I can prove the implication directly but maybe I'm just missing something simple.

Comment: It's okay, don't worry about it. I was more interested in the second part  anyway, i.e. the boundedness of $(λ-1)R(λ)$ on $\mathbb T \setminus\{1\}$