# Estimation of $\int_{|z| = 1 + \varepsilon} \frac{|\mathrm{d}z|}{|z - 1|}$ when $\varepsilon \to 0^+$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Consider the following family of integrals for $\varepsilon > 0$:
$$I(\varepsilon) := \int_{|z| = 1 + \varepsilon} \frac{|\mathrm{d}z|}{|z - 1|} = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(1 + \varepsilon)\,\mathrm{d}\theta}{|(1+\varepsilon)e^{i\theta} - 1|}$$

> **Question**: The objective would be to show the following behaviour:
> $$\liminf_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\, I(\varepsilon) < +\infty$$
> However, is this true?

The first red flag I'm seeing is that the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{|e^{i\theta} - 1|}$, which would be a limit-candidate for $I(\varepsilon)$, is infinite, as we have $|e^{i\theta} - 1| = 2 \sin(\theta/2)$ on $[0, 2\pi]$ and:
$$\int_{\delta}^{\pi - \delta} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sin \theta} = \left[\frac{1}{2} \ln\left(\frac{1 + \cos \theta}{1 - \cos \theta}\right)\right]_\delta^{\pi - \delta} = \ln\left(\frac{1 - \cos \delta}{1 + \cos \delta}\right) \xrightarrow[\delta \to 0^+]{} +\infty$$
but this of course does not eliminate the possibility for the $I(\varepsilon)$s to converge to a different, finite limit altogether.

Feel free to edit and re-tag when/if appropriate or necessary.

**Skippable paragraph (motivation)**: This is motivated by the following question, though I haven't put functional analysis related tags because it is not the main focus of the present question (though if you know an answer to OP's problem feel free to answer on their question!): [If $\{ (λ-1)R(λ;T) \colon |λ|>1\}$ is bounded then so is $\{ (λ-1)R(λ;T) \colon |λ|=1, \ λ \neq 1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4880530/1104384) .
To answer the question of OP, I'm attempting to show that if we have a bounded operator $T$ such that the resolvent satisfies the inequality $|\lambda - 1|\|R(\lambda, T)\| \leq M$ for some constant $M$ and all $\lambda$ in the complement of the closed unit disk, then the norms of the $T^k$s, $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$ (strictly positive integers), are bounded by a constant (we say that $T$ is *power bounded* if that's the case) (this resolvent condition is similar but not identical to the definition of a Kreiss bounded operator, where $|\lambda - 1|$ is replaced with $|\lambda| - 1$).
The equality $$T^k = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\lambda| = 1 + \varepsilon} \lambda^k R(\lambda, T)\mathrm{d}\lambda$$
is then what makes the $I(\varepsilon)$ naturally appear with the resolvent condition given and use of the triangle inequality, since we have:
$$\|T^k\| \leq K (1 + \varepsilon)^{k} I(\varepsilon)$$
for some constant $K$, hence:
$$\|T^k\| \leq K \liminf_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \,(1 + \varepsilon)^{k} I(\varepsilon) = K \liminf_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \, I(\varepsilon)$$
independently of $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this appraoch to OP's question won't work because the integrals diverge to $+\infty$ (as I expected/feared).

Indeed, we have:
$$\begin{split} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{|(1+\varepsilon)e^{i\theta} - 1|} &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{\left((1+\varepsilon)\cos \theta - 1\right)^2 + (1 + \varepsilon)^2\sin^2 \theta}}\\
&\geq \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{-2(1+\varepsilon)\cos \theta + 1 + (1 + \varepsilon)^2}}\\
&\geq \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{-2(1+\varepsilon)\cos \theta + (1 + \varepsilon) + (1 + \varepsilon)^2}}\\
&\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \varepsilon}}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{-2\cos \theta + 1 + (1 + \varepsilon)}}\\
&\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \varepsilon}}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{4\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) + \varepsilon}}\end{split}$$
Yet, thanks to the monotone convergence theorem applied to any decreasing subsequence $(\varepsilon_n)_n$ tending to $0^+$ when $n \to +\infty$, and since the integrands converge to $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2 \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}$, we do obtain that:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{4\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) + \varepsilon}} \xrightarrow[\varepsilon \to 0^+]{} +\infty$$
thanks to what I said in the body of my question, hence:
$$I(\varepsilon) \xrightarrow[\varepsilon \to 0^+]{} +\infty$$